# How to decode attachment in Waves?

Tags: wavesplatform

How can I decode waves tx attachment with javascript?

```
"attachment": "3vqXJBWJCU"
```

Need to decode in 1d1c0f375c646b70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This attachment is base58 encoded. If you need fast decoding you can use any online base58 encoding/decoding service, but it's not recommended to encode/decode seed phrase online.
By the way, I'm using this one JavaScript base58 decoder: https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58

Here is an example of decoding:

```
const bs58 = require('bs58')

const attachment = '3vqXJBWJCU'
const bytes = bs58.decode(attachment)
console.log(bytes.toString('hex'))
// => MESSAGE
```